# pointer warning (Parallel computing)

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mutex

I want my program to compute definite integral of a function by splitting the [a;b] segment into N parts and computing it using threads. The problem is that I struggle to run it properly, I get the following warning: *cast to pointer from integer of different size*
I tried to solve it by creating a pointer but then it computes very randomly (sometimes it runs only the first thread or forgets to run one of them). Here is the part of the code including my attempt:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    pthread_t * threads;
    int i;
    int *j = &i;
    p = (int) strtol (argv[1], 0, 10);
    if(!(threads = (pthread_t*) malloc (p*sizeof(pthread_t)))) {
        std::cout<<"Not enough memory"<<std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
        if (pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, &run, (void*)j)) { //here comes a trouble
            std::cout << "Cannot create thread" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
        if (pthread_join( threads[i], NULL)) {
            std::cout << "Waiting error" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
    }
    free(threads);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    std::cout << "Integral f(x) from 0 to 1 = " << S << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: If you have access to C++11 or higher you might want to use [`<thread>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread).  It makes threading a lot easier.

Comment: Don' use `malloc()` and `free()` in C++ programs, please.

Comment: Your program is not complete. For example, what is `S`? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please, try to use better naming. A pointer to a loop variable named `i` (`i` itself of course is ok) called `j` is pretty confusing, because `j` usually also is used as a common loop var.

Comment: @JesperJuhl it is a part of code, the rest makes no sense in terms of problem anyways, S is a static variable, every thread adds it's sum to it

Comment: @Иван Иванов well, if `S` is not atomic or otherwise protected from concurrent access, then accessing it from multiple threads is going to be a problem (bug).

Comment: This code has a data race on it. The warning is one of it's symptoms

Comment: No. Warning and error are completely unrelated. Иван Иванов's posting states, that he/she tried to cast `i` to `void*`. That produced the **Warning**. _And only then_ he/she tried to fix the warning issue by using a pointer to `i`. That produced the **Error** (data race like described). The warning is caused by a different bit width cast, the error is caused by a data race.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning in your first approach (to cast `i` to `void *`) was caused by a different bit width between `int` and `void *`. Most likely your ints are 32 bit, and your pointers are 64 (common in a 64 bit build).
It just tells you that you are doing something potentially dangerous (assigning a variable to a pointer of different size), but since `pthread_create` awaits a `void *` (which it does not use as a real pointer, but only as a transfer variable to your thread startup), you can't change that, and it does no harm (as long as you don't use it as a real pointer and don't exceed the numerical limits of the different bit widths)

Your pointer approach you tried to fix the warning on the other hand made everything worse. The problem is, that the pointer never changes in your loop.

`j` always points to `i`, but the content of i changes during your loop. When your thread startup now is called (already in its own thread context, and probably already some time later), it gets the *current* content of i in your main thread context - which might be already one or even more loop iterations later. This is probably the source of the "randomness" you observe and is a real error.

So you can either write a (commented) ignore pragma for that warning for your compiler, or you can choose a size for i, which matches the pointer size - but ignoring the warning is even safer in your case, because pointer sizes may vary between builds (32/64 bit)

So indeed the solution would be:

```
for ( i = 0; i < p; ++i) {

// important: just an example. Pragmas and warnings vary per
// compiler, please look in your compiler's reference:
#pragma disable_bit_width_cast_warning

    //i instead of j - no pointer, just a copy of i
    if (pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, &run, (void*)i)) { 

#pragma enable_bit_width_cast_warning

        std::cout << "Cannot create thread" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Another solution would be to really use a pointer - but that pointer would have to be a copy. And you would have to delete it after use in your thread:

```
for ( i = 0; i < p; ++i) {
    // hand over a copy of i to your thread startup.
    // you'll have to cast the void* back to int* in your thread startup, 
    // and don't forget to delete it!
    if (pthread_create(threads + i, NULL, &run, (void*) new int(i))) { 
        std::cout << "Cannot create thread" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Or you can - like NathanOliver already suggested in a comment - use `std::thread`, which is preferrably, because it's safer, easier and nicer to use and hasn't got this `void *` issue. (Casting around imho always has a smell) Here's a nice [description and example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread)

Comment: I'm having trouble following between: *"This is probably the source of the "randomness" you observe...."* and *"It's safe to ignore the warning in that case."* Can you clarify what a "correct" solution would be.

Comment: Thanks, I hope it's more understandable now.

Comment: The problem is exactly as you describe in your first two paragraphs. But your solution is not clear. The OP *does* need to heed the warning ... and needs to pass the value of `i` somehow as an argument to the thread start routine. That's the information your answer is lacking IMO.

Comment: Do you mean something like that?

Comment: Dear downvoter, its really helpful to vote down and don't tell why. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2328447 Thank you very much for help! It is always good to try different solutions and gain such an experience

Comment: OP's code has a data race in it. You suggested to suppress the warning, and live with the race.

Comment: Casting `i` to `void *` doesn't issue a data race. Why should it? It is just transporting `i`'s content to the thread startup. Only handing over a direct, non-copied pointer to `i` to the thread startup causes a data race - which I described correctly I assume - but that on the other hand isn't the cause of the warning. Or am I wrong? If yes, it would be really nice if you could exactly tell me where.

Comment: You don't explain your solutions to solve the race until **after** you claim *"For the warning on the other hand it can be said that it's safe to ignore it in that case."* No. The OP cannot ignore the warning until **after** he/she has fixed the race.

Comment: Иван Иванов's posting states, that he/she tried to cast `i` to `void*`. That produced the **Warning**. _And only then_ he/she tried to fix the warning issue by using a pointer to `i`. That produced the **Error** (data race like described). The warning is caused by a different bit width cast, the error is caused by a data race. Warning and error are **completely unrelated**. Please don't read only the code, read his/her posting as well.

Comment: I changed the order, hopefully it's understandable now.